# Liferay redirect to action URL after successful logged in

Tags: java, redirect, liferay-6, liferay-6.2

I have a requirement that if users is not logged in the URL will redirect to user's logIn page and if user already logged in then it will redirect to it's particular action.
So for non logged in User after clicking on action URL I need to redirect to login page and after successful login user should redirect to action URL page not last visited page.
Currently after successful login user will redirect to last visited page.

I tried below properties in portal-ext.properties for redirect to action URL page but didn't work :

```
auth.forward.by.last.path=true
auth.forward.by.redirect=true
```

and also tried with "/c/portal/login?redirect=currenturl" and "/c/portal/login?saveLastPath=0".

I am using LR 6.2 EE sp12.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Default Landing Page in the Control Panel:

Portal -> Settings -> General -> Navigation

Or, in the portal-ext.properties, set:

```
default.landing.page.path=/web/guest/home
```

DOC: https://web.liferay.com/es/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Customizing+the+default+page+after+login